# wso2 api manager artifact association error multi tenant

Tags: multi-tenant, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

So we have set up a api manager with a identity server as a key manager. Carbon.super is the only tenant that can create APIs in api manager, with no issues.
Internal/everyone have been granted with every permission on their tenants, users on different tenants can log onto the api manager publisher and store, on other tenants the users cannot create any api's with the following errors on the API manager removed the (at) references for making it less to read.

```
TID: [1] [] [2019-02-11 12:58:19,669] @test.dk [1] [AM]ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl} -  Error in associating lifecycle for the artifact. id: d9afaaa9-a2fe-479f-927b-658dc34393b6, path: /apimgt/applicationdata/provider/admin-AT-test.dk/WorldBank/1/api. {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl}
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Couldn't find aspectName 'APILifeCycle'
TID: [1] [] [2019-02-11 12:58:19,680] @test.dk [1] [AM]ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider} -  Error while performing registry transaction operation {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider}
org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.exception.GovernanceException: Error in associating lifecycle for the artifact. id: d9afaaa9-a2fe-479f-927b-658dc34393b6, path: /apimgt/applicationdata/provider/admin-AT-test.dk/WorldBank/1/api.
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-02-11 12:58:19,684] ERROR {JAGGERY.site.blocks.item-design.ajax.add:jag} -  org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while performing registry transaction operation (/publisher/modules/api/add.jag#108)
```

for the full issue log go to this link: https://pastebin.com/9LDv3u8Q

i can create applications on the /store with the tenant users.

the apilifecycle doesnt seem to be linked to tenants made thus making it impossible to make API's on the server

i have tried to copy APILifeCycle.xml from the api manager to the same location on the Identity server. the carbon super does have the apilifecycle in the extensions tab on carbon part of the apimanager but tenants does not.

i have have been researching on how i could fix this some other sources i have attempted with no luck is 
Link: http://ishara-cooray.blogspot.com/2018/01/how-to-fix-orgwso2carbonregistrycoreexc.html
It have been set up like this link: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager
What i expect to happen
Users from tenants that can create and publish api's on their tenant domain

Answer (score 0):

We have provided a fix for this issue and if you could take a WUM update (https://wso2.com/updates/wum) you could get the patch for this issue.

If you do not have access to WUM updates, Then try putting the APILifecycle.xml file to /repository/resources/lifecycles folder in IS  (this shouldn't work with existing tenants. New tenants should work). For existing tenants, you could log in to management console (https://localhost:9443/carbon) and navigate to Extensions > Configure > Lifecycles and upload the APILifecycle.

Thanks

Comment: "**For existing tenants, you could log in to management console (https://localhost:9443/carbon) and navigate to Extensions > Configure > Lifecycles and upload the APILifecycle.**"

in my case when i attempt to do the following the api manager tells me that it cannot save the lifecycle into the tenant which on the API manager log tells me that there is a null pointer exception